# Appropriate method to shard a BigQuery table via DBT

Tags: for-loop, sharding, dbt

I am working with a rather large BigQuery table - let us call it `lt` - and am considering the possibility of creating a sharded version of it by using DBT. More specifically, I would like to be able to split the rows of the original table `lt` into subcollections grouped by date (`lt` contains a date column) and output the entire sequence of such smaller tables via DBT.

In order to create an individual fragment-table, I am considering the following straight-forward DBT code:

```
{{config(alias='lt'+'_'+var('date_suffix'))}}


WITH final AS (
    SELECT * FROM 'lt'
    WHERE FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", date)=var('date_suffix')
)


{{dbt_audit(cte_ref='final')}}
```

however the main issue is **how to execute such code** for a `date_suffix` *ranging over a span of dates corresponding to 2-3 years,* so as to obtain the entire desired succession of shards from the original `lt`? In principle this would entail some form of *for loop* over a range of approximately 2 * 365=730 dates, but the exact manner in which such a for loop should be implemented are beyond me. If anyone could offer me some guidance, it would be more than appreciated.